# How to set automatic deletion of folder with Box REST api V2?

Tags: box-api, box, boxapiv2

I want to set automatic delete date for a folder in Box through REST api. I don't see any option for it now? Is it possible through Box v2 api?

Answer (score 1):

What is the particular use case? If it's to prevent a user from having access to a folder, perhaps setting an unshare date may work for you? I don't believe you can do the same for the deletion of a folder.

Is creating a service with a timer job that executes the delete folder request out of the question?

Comment: No. I want to set storage expiration on a file/folder not share expire. Indeed box allows this through its property settings from UI interface. I want to do the same through REST apis.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe this is yet possible.

Comment: OMG, I came from the future 2020. Box still hasn't have the option for auto-delete files by an expiration date from their API. Shame Box, Shame! but they have the option to add it manually from ther UI. Amazing!